# How to renew Google Chrome certificate (NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID)?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl

After installing a new Windows 7 laptop, my time was set a few hours in the future.
Consequently, Google Mail (and other sites like stack overflow or tumblr) are displaying **`NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID`** errors in *Google Chrome* (see below).

Serching the web points to renewal of Google Chrome's certificate as possible solution, but I found no succeeding procedures to do that.

### How can I solve the NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID error?

[image: NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID demo]

***Environment***:

- Windows 7 SP1
- Chrome 41.0.2272.118 m
- AVG Internet Security 2015

Comment: This error is caused by AVG

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the *stackexchange* suggestions, the anti-virus emerged as a possible culprit.
Indeed, when setting the `AVG` as below (disabling `Online Shield`), the issue is solved.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Whichever Anti-virus you use, de-select (uncheck) the box for HTTPS scanning.

Comment: So, if you go into the Windows certificate store and remove AVG's `Man in the Middle` certificate for each website you have issues with so it recreates them, you can then reenable HTTPS packet scanning?